# No Module named 'fastapi' - Ubuntu environment

Tags: python, fastapi

Though I have pip and pip3 installed fastapi library in my Ubuntu based workstation, I get a weird error saying

> No module named 'fastapi'.

I have been scratching my head since two days ago as the same code works in other laptop with same Ubuntu environment.

[image]

Uninstalled and reinstalled fastapi library

Comment: So first of all you are using python for the root user. You can try `sudo pip install fastapi`, but it's not good approach. Create a virtual environment in the folder, activate it, install the packages and then run the app. [Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not using the correct environment to run your code.
Either, 1. install the package `fast-api` in the environment you running the code in or 2. switch to the other one the packages are installed in:

for 1:
`sudo /bin/python3 -m pip install "fastapi[all]"`

in this case you should be able to use the fast-api package
Note: the other packages you use are probably not installed as well

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you are using the wrong env? It looks like you're using vscode so you can [specify the interpeter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter)
2. Try `pip install --upgrade pip` and then `pip install fastapi again`
3. Try using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), and do `conda install -c conda-forge fastapi`